# can we setup single storm ui for all nimbus?

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology, apache-storm-configs

my question is, can we use only one storm ui for multiple nimbus?. because if nimbus is fail on the machine, the ui also getting error on the browser. even not a leader nimbus is changed as a leader (which is running on another machine )

instead of running storm ui for every nimbus running machine, can we set storm ui commonly for all the nimbus ? if can how to achieve

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can deploy only one UI instance for the whole cluster no matter its size.
2. If your cluster running more than 20+ supervisors host I would recommend spawning 3 instances of nimbus to resilience. From my real production practice, the number of nimbus instances should be odd (1-3-5) to remain quorum in case of unavailability (1 for 3, 2 for 5), but 3 is quite enough up to 100 supervisors.
3. Same rule is for zookeeper instances (1-3-5).